# How is the power gained from exhaust of an engine calculated?

Tags: propulsion, vtol

Ryan XV-5 Vertifan used exhaust gas from engine to rotate the fan inside the wing.

If I want to design an aircraft using this propulsion system how can I calculate how much power I can get from a specific engine exhaust?

Comment: This answer from space exploration stack exchange gives the formula for calculating power of an exhaust jet https://space.stackexchange.com/a/20075/6944 You need to know the thrust generated by the exhaust and the velocity of the exhaust.

Answer (score -1):

We really answer this question in 2 parts.

The first is how much **thrust** the engine can generate at a given airspeed, either in pure thrust from exhaust gasses, or torque transferred to a mechanically rotating device, which in turn creates thrust.

> this quality is known as [specific impulse](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specific_impulse)

Fortunately for aircraft such as the [Ryan XV-5](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ryan_XV-5_Vertifan), the [F35B](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolls-Royce_LiftSystem), and helicopters, converting engine torque to vertical rotor lifting force, at lower airspeeds, can be far more efficient than simply exhausting gasses vertically.

Helicopters, such as the [R-22](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robinson_R22),  can generate over 10 pounds of lifting force per horsepower.  Propeller driven aircraft get 3-4 lbs per horsepower flying horizontally, turbofans and turbojets less but at much higher speeds$^1$.

If you are considering a design such as the XV-5, power requirements per pound weight would be in the "ball park" of the F-35B.  With a larger a rotor over the top, like [this](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_UH-1_Iroquois) one, they would be less.

Specific to the [Ryan XV5 VTOL system](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Cutaway-view-of-the-Ryan-XV-5-pnuematically-Rim-Driven-Fans-1_fig1_346002409), which was pneumaticly driven, lift could be theoretically calculated by the efficiency of the bleed air to drive the fans to an RPM sufficient to generate the amount of lift needed.

I must admit one aspect of the VTOL system struck me beyond theoretical calculations ... the lack of need for **mechanical linkages**.  The pneumatic drive was an ingenious application of the ["turbocompound"](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turbo-compound_engine) energy recovery systems used in the huge piston engines of the day.

But again ... **no mechanical linkages**.  If it gets shot up, close the bleeds and land normally.

Furthermore ... could these fans be run hydraulicly, or even electricly?  Perhaps a design worth re-visiting.

$^1$ yes, jets do generate rotating mechanical energy, or "horsepower", to turn their turbines and fans.

Comment: So how do you calculate it?

Comment: My point is, if one cannot calculate thrust by following the instructions given in your answer, then you really haven't actually answered the question... have you?

Comment: @MichaelHall "calculating" the thrust of an experimental system is really a "chicken and egg" issue.  I favor testing, and deriving mathematical models from testing.  A highlighted section on "specific impulse" (for various propulsion systems) is there for your reading.  It should come as no surprise that (ducted) fans produce around 3x more thrust than "exhaust gasses" under static conditions.

Answer (score -1):

To find the power you can get from the engine, we must calculate the energy of the exhaust gas and multiply it with the efficiency of the turbine. Note that this only gives the power output at the engine. To get the full answer, the efficiency of the transmission and of the fan in the wing need to be taken in to account too.

The power of the flow has two components, it's pressure and it's velocity. This is different from a rocket in vacuum or most general jet engines because in that case there is no pressure component. In vacuum there is no pressure, so the pressure component disappears. Most jet engines are designed to have an exit pressure similar the air pressure, so the pressure also drops out. Even if there is a difference, the energy from pressure is usually very small compared to the energy from the velocity. If we look at the flow in the engine before a turbine, the pressure is usually very high and the velocity low..

The general equation for thrust can be found here:
[General Thrust Equation](https://www.grc.nasa.gov/www/k-12/VirtualAero/BottleRocket/airplane/thrsteq.html)

A more detailed description of how to calculate the power can be found here:
[Power Turbine Thermodynamics](https://www.grc.nasa.gov/www/k-12/airplane/powtrbth.html)